# Aligning divs center next to eachother with valign: top

Tags: css, html, alignment

Take a look here http://www.basenharald.nl/3d.
For the home part i put on some black borders so you can see what i mean.

The problem:
I need to position the 2 blocks (the "hey"block and the right part) next to each other in the center and position them individual from there on out.
The logical thing to do is to use display: inline block. Now the problem is that it does not valign top, so i cannot position them with margins.

Basically what i want to do is position the "hey"part slightly to the left and the "right"part slightly to the right and a tat downwards.

What is the best way to do so? It needs to be centered all time cause of the perspective effect and resolutions.
Hope i am clear enough, otherwise just ask.

this is the css part i am talking about:

```
#home-welkom { text-align:left; width: 465px; margin: 360px 400px 100px; 230px; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;  color:#787778; font-size:11px; border:1px solid black; }
#home-right { text-align:left; width: 330px; margin: 50px 0px 0 0; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block; border:1px solid black; }
```

Also not that the margin property does not influence the divs at all

Comment: Maybe you could sketch out how you want the page to lay out?  Also just a suggestion - "Pssst" doesn't say social media to me, but "Share" does.

Comment: could you post the exact code you want to fix?

Comment: thanks for the tip. The sketch is not needed sinc other parts of the website should be positioned otherwise. i just need to position them manually throughout css without them influencing eachother (what display:inline-block does)

Comment: @checkenginelight did so, the css part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to rethink your design strategy. Here's a few pointers:

- Use divs instead of lists to layout your page (lists are good for menus, etc)
- margins can only be used once per class
- use div floats to position your divs side by side
- store your javascripts externally this way your code will be cleaner

Now for your question this is what you're looking for to position your elements:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; text-align: left">
<div id="leftcol" style="float: left; width: 400px;">left column</div>
<div id="rightcol" style="float: left; width: 400px;">right column</div>
</div>
```

Finally I would make sure and validate my code and you can do so here: http://validator.w3.org/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was not the actual answer, but the wrapper idea brought me to it, therefor i will mark this as right answer