# Trouble with making two divs side by side in html

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm making a website, and I need to have two divs side by side, but instead one is below the other.
I am using
    align="left"
on the first one, and
    align="right"
on the second.

Here is the full body of the page - http://pastebin.com/Cxg1RbXW

Also, here's the style.css sheet - http://pastebin.com/pTaV6AsQ

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps using the float property and float both to the left? (That way they should line up against one another)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aligning divs center next to eachother with valign: top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531497/aligning-divs-center-next-to-eachother-with-valign-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to float your divs so they can reside side by side together:

```
#right, #left {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `float:left|right`. Check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float).

Here's [a working fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/32Zkq/3/).

```
.left, .right {
    float:left;
}
```